# Google Maps Android not Authenticating

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app on Android Studio and tried to create a Google Maps Activity.

Android Studio Automatically created the Activity and the google_maps_api.xml file. Then, I created the Google Maps Android Key on Google Developers Console and copied it into the mentioned xml file. I also

When I run the application It shows the following error:

```
01-28 13:16:21.279 5689-5863/com.comunity.dxmobile.tooltester E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
01-28 13:16:21.279 5689-5863/com.comunity.dxmobile.tooltester E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-28 13:16:21.284 5689-5863/com.comunity.dxmobile.tooltester E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                         Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                         Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                            API Key: AIza****vlmk
                                                                                            Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 57:29:****:77:1A:71;com.comunity.dxmobile.tooltester
```

I tried to add the following line to the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

The metadata tag was also added

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.comunity.dxmobile.tooltester"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

This is the google_maps_aspi.xml file

```
<resources>
<!-- This was my generated key -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">MY********KEY</string>
</resources>
```

I also checked in the developer console and the api is enable. Not the "Google Maps Android API v2" but the "Google Maps Android API".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added the following to your AndroidManifest.xml, at the `<application>` tag level:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

You should also include the generated key from the Google Developer Console in a new resource file keys.xml, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">INSERT YOUR GENERATED KEY</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi @MadaT, I updated my Question with the section of the Manifest and the xml file with the code you suggest, i forgot to put it on the Question, but I already had it.

Answer (score 0):

did u add the meta data related to maps in manifest like below

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="@string/testgoogleapikey" />
```

Comment: Hi @Nidhin, I updated my Question with the xml file with the code you suggest, i forgot to put it on the Question, but I already had it.

Comment: hi @an3sarmiento, ok how did u generate the key for sha1 hash. I mean when u create a map app in console.google.com , you have to put SHA1 hash key to get your api credential access for the maps. Have u used your Default Keystore to generate the hash, or you created a new Keystore for your app. Build the app with which the keystore is linked to google

Comment: Hi @Nidhin, this is a screenshot of the google console. Look that the SHA1 hash key, corresponds to the one printed in the error message (http://i68.tinypic.com/25pmlj6.png). To answer your question, this hash key was generated automatically by the Activity creator.

Comment: @an3sarmiento , u created the sha1 key using gradle build itself? y im asking this because the keystotre that u used for keystore and the keystore u used for building ur apk should match

Answer (score 0):

In your console log: exception says
 Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

Please check your google developer account, you need  enable the Map API.

Login with your account and check for API is enable or disable.
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_android_backend/overview?project

Comment: Good, If you are sure you have done right steps then.

Let us examine your exception again closely, Authorization is failed,  Seems your app is using wrong credentials to connect to server.

Try to uninstall you application and run again. May be your credentials are cashed.

Comment: Hi @Sundeep, this is a screenshot of the google console. Look that the SHA1 hash key, corresponds to the one printed in the error message (i68.tinypic.com/25pmlj6.png). I tried to uninstall and deploy the app again and the error message is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,go to the google [website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert) and find the "Displaying the debug certificate fingerprint" section and follow the instructions, it'll work!